# How to edit text in already created files using C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am new to C++ programming. I want to:
i) open an already created text file in my program
ii)  read its content to match some specific string
iii) replace the content with some new string value in that very same file

I have tried to find any solution from google, but failed.
any help would highly be appreciated...
here is an example of what i am intending to do...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    string name="ABC";
    string designation="Student";
    int age=19;
    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Data.txt,ios::in|ios::out|ios::app");
        outfile<<setw(10)<<name<<setw(10)<<designation<<setw(10)<<age;
    outfile>>name;
    if(name=="ABC")
    {
            name="XYZ";
            outfile<<name;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your `outfile.open()` call, you might want to change the position of the closing quote.

Comment: The `main()` function of a C++ program always returns an `int` to the operating system, never `void`. See also `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, you need to read the file, make the change, and then write the file. If the replacement you're making is of a different length, then you need to rewrite the contents of the file after the modification such that they are moved down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my file contains data about students including their whole information and status of their suggestions. I want my program to move through each student's data and check its status. If the status is "pending", then it should be made "processing", and if it is "processing", then it should change it to "done". I cant manage to write whole of it to new files twice. Is not there any way to just change the status?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that. Files are stream oriented devices. At the end of the day, the file is on disk somewhere, and disks don't have an automatic means to move blocks around as whole chunks for you -- all the blocks have to be read in and written out as streams.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will try to sort it out using the way you suggested before.